# Какова должна быть структура react.js приложения?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, reactjs, app, project

Доброго времени суток.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при написании react приложения его обязательно надо разделять на 2 части: БД и клиентская? Есть ли возможность этого избежать и есть ли в этом смысл?

Comment: реакт не умеет ничего за рамками рендеринга интерфейса, и делает это или в браузере, и на сервере, чтобы отдать в браузер готовый хтмл

Answer (score 0):

Кто Вам сказал что это должны быть 2 части? Причем именно БД? Реакт конечно дает Вам возможность выстрелить в ногу, но это делать вовсе не обязательно. Структура базируется на требованиях и может варьироваться в зависимости от Ваших предпочтений.[image: у меня вот так, например]